# Beautifulsoup replace colspan=2 with single col

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse data from rows which occasionally have a colspan=2 which spoils my ability to target data to extract.
What I'd like to do is remove the 'colspan=2' from the table element every time it occurs:

```
#replace
<td colspan="2" class="time">10:00 AM</td>
#with
<td>635</td>
```

Is this possible? And can I work it into a conditional if then else?

Here's a more verbose example:

```
<table>
<tr class="playerRow even">
<td class="pos">1</td>
<td><span class="rank"></span> -</td>
<td class="player"><p class="playerName">John doe</p></td>
<td class="background">X</td>
<td>345</td> #THIS ELEMENT FREQUENT
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td style=""></td>
</tr><

<tr class="playerRow odd">
<td class="pos">1</td>
<td><span class="rank"></span> -</td>
<td class="player"><p class="playerName">John doe</p></td>
<td class="background">X</td>
<td colspan="2" class="myClass" style="">3:15 PM</td> #THIS ELEMENT OCCASIONAL
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td style=""></td>
</tr>

<tr class="playerRow odd">
<td class="pos">1</td>
<td><span class="rank"></span> -</td>
<td class="player"><p class="playerName">John doe</p></td>
<td class="background">X</td>
<td>22</td> #THIS ELEMENT FREQUENT
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td style=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So whenever I come across the colspan I'd like to replace it with a plain td, so it doesn't shunt the row elements across and mess up my count.

Comment: Can you give a more complete example of the data you are working with?

Comment: Thanks for replying, here's a more verbose table:

Comment: Just edit your question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will convert:

`<td colspan="2" class="myClass" style="">3:15 PM</td>`

to:

`<td>3:15 PM</td>`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bs = BeautifulSoup(html)

for x in bs.findAll("td"):
    if "colspan" in x.attrs:
        x.attrs = {}
```

Do you want it to remove the value also?